# TypeError: Invalid locator error using By.linkText containing dot characters (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, linktext, partiallinktext

I've looked around on other SO questions, but I don't see anything that could help me. My error, as the title suggests, is the `TypeError: Invalid locator` error. Here is part of my code (where I think the problem occurs), so that you can see what is wrong with it:

```
(async function(){
            let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
            try 
            {
                await driver.get(stockLink);
                if (driver.findElement(By.linkText("View at Amazon.co.uk") === true))
                {
                    let amazonLink = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.linkText('View at Amazon.co.uk')), 5000);
                    await amazonLink.click();
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                await driver.quit();
            }
            
        })();
```

All variables used in this portion of code have been assigned a value.

Edit:

I'll explain what the code is supposed to do, if it helps:

The code clicks on a link, which leads to another link on Amazon. I can get the first link to open, but after the program attempts to open the second link, I get the `TypeError: Invalid locator` error.

Edit 2:

Here is the stack trace:

```
Trace
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\project\index.js:55:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)     
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)    
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)   
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
at C:\Users\user\project\index.js:75:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

Edit 3: Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: Invalid locator
    at Object.check [as checkedLocator] (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:405:9)
    at Driver.findElement (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:971:18)
    at C:\Users\user\project\index.js:66:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) **`.`** is interpreted differently, maorly to denote *`classnames`*. Hence the error.

---

### Solution

You can change the [Class By](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/by_exports_By.html) from:

```
By.linkText('View at Amazon.co.uk')
```

To:

```
By.partialLinkText('View at Amazon')
```

---

### Update

Effectively your line of code will be:

```
if (await driver.findElement(By.linkText("View at Amazon.co.uk")) == true))
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Edit: Tried, didn't work.

Comment: Wait. Let me change some syntax around and try again. I might have done something wrong.

Comment: After changing the if statement to `if (driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText('View at Amazon')) === true)`, I get a new error message:

Comment: `Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51598
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:273:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:462:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)`

Comment: @fr0stbyte Can you await for `driver.findElement(By.linkText("View at Amazon.co.uk")` before evaluation?

Comment: you mean something like `var amazonLink = await driver.findElement(By.linkText("View at Amazon.co.uk"))` before the `if` statement?

Comment: @fr0stbyte How about `if (await driver.findElement(By.linkText("View at Amazon.co.uk")) == true))`?

Comment: I tried that and there seems to be no errors at all. However, the expected result is not produced. Only the first link (which has a page which leads to the Amazon link) opens. At this point, it may only be a logical fault, which I need to change myself.

Comment: @fr0stbyte Of coarse you got rid of the error `TypeError: Invalid locator` which was your main concern. However, _`expected result is not produced`_ sounds like a different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much for saving me hours of headaches.